# Why is it called the everlasting gospel in Rev. 14:6?

Tags: word-study, revelation

Why is the gospel called the everlasting gospel in Rev. 14:6:

> And I saw another angel fly in the midst of heaven, having the everlasting gospel to preach unto them that dwell on the earth, and to every nation, and kindred, and tongue, and people,

Why call it everlasting? In what way will it be everlasting and applicable in heaven one day?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? I'm finding it hard to think of any perspectives of the Gospel which treat it in any way as a temporary thing.

Comment: I read this in the HNQ as [everlasting gobstopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everlasting_Gobstopper)

Answer (score 2):

**Everlasting**

The Greek word is αἰώνιος, frequently rendered in English as *eternal* or *everlasting*.

Strong's provides the following usage of the word:

> age-long, and therefore: practically eternal, unending; partaking of the character of that which lasts for an age, as contrasted with that which is brief and fleeting

This context of "age-long" is often overlooked in modern thought. A useful example is to imagine a timeline.

Whether the timeline we are examining stretches from 200 BC to 1945, or from last Tuesday to today, or something else, is irrelevant. We're looking at a timeline that covers some expanse of time.

Something that is αἰώνιος *with respect to that timeline* is something that is present or true at any point on that timeline. It exists beyond the upper and lower bounds of the timeline (whatever those bounds are) and is therefore an unfailing characteristic of the era covered by the timeline.

This is why it is not incorrect to refer to someone's patient attendance as "an eternal vigil". It doesn't mean the person was there watching since t minus infinity, it means they were unfailingly there the entire time.

--

**Application to the passage**

The stated context here is that this is given *unto them that dwell on the earth*. The gospel is αἰώνιος to them that dwell on the earth. The gospel is unfailingly reliable the entire time.

The role that the principles of the gospel taught on the earth will play in heaven, or in any context outside of dwelling on the earth, is not stated. This is certainly not to say that gospel principles will no longer be relevant in heaven, but that such is not the focus of this passage.

In this passage the gospel is a message ("good news") being delivered to those who dwell on the earth. It is an unfailing feature and can be relied upon at any point; it fully encompasses the scope of their existence on earth. There is no point on that timeline where they cannot trust it.

---

**Post-script**

I did want to acknowledge another dimension of "eternal" which, though not explicit in this passage, could be inferred through a scripture-interprets-scripture view:

This good news isn't just any good news. It's the good news of the Son of God (see Mark 1:1).

*Eternal* is an attribute of God's nature; therefore, eternal is an appropriate descriptor of His fundamental program, His good news.

Comment: I agree with this answer. +1 :))) I think it's a better explanation than the one I had. My guess was that the gospel was "eternal" in the sense that its effects are eternal, i.e. how believing in the gospel results in *eternal* life. Though I think your explanation makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two reasons why the Gospel is called "eternal" or "everlasting":

**1. The Gospel is the Gospel of the everlasting Kingdom of God**

- Matt 24:14 - And this **gospel of the kingdom** will be preached in all the world as a testimony to all nations, and then the end will come.
- 2 Peter 1:11 - and you will receive a lavish reception into the **eternal kingdom** of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ.
- Ps 145:13 - Your kingdom is an **everlasting kingdom**, and Your dominion endures through all generations. The LORD is faithful in all His words and kind in all His actions.
- Dan 4:3 - How great are His signs, how mighty His wonders! His kingdom is an **eternal kingdom**; His dominion endures from generation to generation.
- Dan 7:27 - Then the sovereignty, dominion, and greatness of the kingdoms under all of heaven will be given to the people, the saints of the Most High. His kingdom will be an **everlasting kingdom**, and all rulers will serve and obey Him.’

**2. The Gospel contains eternal truths**

- The Gospel is the Gospel of (about) Christ who is eternal, Phil 1:27, 1 Thess 3:2, Mark 1:1, Rom 15:19, 2 Cor 2:12, 9:12, 13, etc.
- It is also the Gospel of God who is eternal, Mark 1:14, 1 Peter 4:17, Rom 15:16, 2 Cor 11:7, 1 Thess 2:8, 9, etc.

That is, this gospel of Jesus Christ teaches eternal truth (2 Thess 2:16) about Jesus and God - it is a gospel about:

- God's eternal grace (Eph 6:24, etc),
- God's eternal love (Ps 103:17, 138:8, 100:5, 136:15)
- God's eternal forgiveness of our sins (Micah 7:19)
- our eternal life in the eternal kingdom of God (Jude 21, John 3:16, 12:25

Thus, "eternal" is a very appropriate epithet for "Gospel".

Answer (score 1):

Of significance is the point that this message is proclaimed by an angel in mid-heaven, as opposed to the gospel message Christians are commissioned to spread throughout the earth. The timing of Rev. 14:6 is also important to consider. This angel is commanded to declare a particular message at a particular time - just before the first reaping of the earth's harvest takes place. This first reaping is of Christ's own people, to be safely gathered into his spiritual, heavenly 'barn'. Immediately after that, the second reaping of the vine of the earth takes place, with the grapes thrown into the winepress of the wrath of God. If people have not been numbered as Christ's own people, they will know only the avenging angels cutting them down. At that time, people are commanded to obey the heavenly message - to fear God, give him the glory and worship him - for the hour of his judgment has arrived.

This is a necessary precursor to understanding the "everlasting" (or 'age-during') aspect of this particular gospel proclamation, which does not explain anything about Jesus Christ, please note. Further, it is addressed to humans on earth who are not yet fearing God, who are not yet giving God the glory, and who are not worshiping him.

***The gospel that is everlasting is that which all in heaven and on earth are commanded to do: to fear God, give him the glory, and worship him. All who do so are blessed; their portion is 'good' indeed! All heaven's angels have been doing that, in the very presence of their Creator, in eternity past, and will continue to do so to all eternity future.*** The only angelic beings who did not do that were cast out of God's presence, cast out of heaven and confined to earth until it is time for them to go to the eternally burning lake of fire - along with all humans who likewise disobey the everlasting gospel.

That gospel is the beginning of the gospel, for the full gospel goes on to explain Jesus Christ and how what he did secured salvation for those who obey the gospel. But those who will not obey the beginning of the gospel will never get to understand the full gospel of Jesus Christ. That was the way it was worked out with John the Baptist, sent with a message to prepare God's people for the coming of the Saviour. All those who heeded the beginning of the gospel back then went on to receive Christ by faith.

It is the same just before the day of judgment starts. The beginning of the gospel (the elementary first part) is declared in mid-heaven to those on earth so that when they are judged, they will not be able to say that they never got to hear the gospel. God knows those who will respond to the beginning of the gospel, and they will be enabled to understand the rest of it. But those who will not even do the basics with regard to their Creator, will never embrace Christ by faith. **Those disobedient ones refused to see the glory of God in creation, which is the gospel shining in creation (Romans 1:18). That is why it is called "everlasting good news"** - read Romans 1:19-20.

God's invisible qualities are clearly seen from the creation of the world, even his eternal power and Godhead, so that they are without excuse. The gospel is all about God and his eternal power and Godhead, magnificently culminating in the glorified Son of God coming to bring in the awesome day of resurrection and judgment. But for those who did not respond to the beginning of the gospel (and so would not respond to the gospel of Christ) there is no response either, on their part, to the one hour of angelic proclamation of the everlasting gospel. And they will have eternity to everlastingly regret not having obeyed it. It is belief in the gospel (whether the beginning of it or the rest of it) that causes people to be obedient to it. Those who obey the beginning of the gospel are prepared to obey the gospel of Jesus Christ and to enjoy the everlasting bliss of being in his presence. **The command of the gospel (fearing, glorifying and worshiping God) is obeyed by all in heaven - joyfully and willingly - for eternity, hence it is the everlasting good news.**

Answer (score 0):

Op asked;
"Why call it everlasting? In what way will it be everlasting and applicable in heaven one day?"

> And I saw another messenger flying in mid-heaven, having good news age-during to proclaim to those dwelling upon the earth, and to every nation, and tribe, and tongue, and people,YLT 14:6

Gospel  which means good news is a unique evangel that will be proclaimed only at this hour of judgment in the book of Revelation. It is God's mercy being revealed before His Judgments begin.   His judgments will be on those who will be taking the mark of the beast.  This eoian evangel is being preached from a messenger flying in mid heaven.  It will be proclaimed to all those who are on the earth over every nation tribe and language.

> He said in a loud voice, “Fear God and give him glory, for the hour of His judgment has come; and worship him who made heaven and earth, the sea and the springs of water.” Rev. 14:7

It is a gospel only for this particular age  and will save them from worshipping the false beast and from Gods fury that is about to be released on the earth.  This is the time where all who are worshipping the wild beast and its image and getting the mark  on his forehand or his hand. It will be the only way to survive in those times.  Those who believe this particular evangel at this time will probably be those who are dying in the Lord as those who are mentioned in Rev. 14:13

> I heard a voice out of the heaven saying to me, ‘Write: Happy are the dead who in the Lord are dying from this time!’ ‘Yes, (saith the Spirit,) That they may rest from their labours — and their works do follow them!’Rev. 14:13

No one, unless especially protected by God, can remain true to Him when they cannot buy or sell, or even socialize with others unless they have the mark of the  and wild beast.

This age lasting gospel will only be proclaimed at this particular time.  It is hard to determine how many days this evangel will be proclaimed.  It only makes sense that everyone on earth will be able to have a chance to hear it.
That is why it is called the eoian or age lasting gospel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book written in the 1890s by Ethelbert W. Bullinger titled „The Witness of the Stars”. In this book the author demonstrates that the constellations, and the signs of the Zodiac, are a perversion of the 12 signs called the Mazzaroth by God in the book of Job. Bullinger suggests that the signs were intended as a set of three heavenly books, each with four chapters, to present the 12 pointed message of God's redemption plan for mankind.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/49018/49018-h/49018-h.html

Comment: This does not seem to address the question at all. A verse in the last book of the Christian Greek scriptures is at issue, in conjunction with the biblical gospel message and its duration - what does 'everlasting gospel' mean?

Comment: Why? Stars are sometimes associated with angels. Abram was told that his offspring will be as stars, which was interpreted qualitatively too. If the  constellations are angels, they are everlasting. Just as the good news their proclaim.

Comment: Certainly, even the book of Revelation speaks of the seven angels of the seven churches being pictorially spoken of as seven stars in the glorified Christ's hand. The problem is, you have not even mentioned 'angels' once in your answer. You seem to assume that everyone will make the connection, but hermeneutics requires evidence to support any claim or answer. Without mentioning angels as connected (somehow) to the book of Job, you are not giving an answer about that angel proclaiming that gospel nor why (the actual Q) it's called 'everlasting'. Besides, the Zodiac is pagan.